# How to keep arrowheads in successive vectors?

Tags: vector, arrowhead

I am generating successive arrows to represent vectors, but when they coincide all the arrowheads disappear except the last. But since they are vectors I want to keep all arrowheads to show direction. Is there a way to do this? Below is code. Also, this would't work until I used Evaluate on the Arrow, but I'm unsure why. Could someone explain? Tks. (This works but is incomplete since I still have to make x[[n]] depend on len)

```
vectors = {0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, -1, 3, 4, 0};
len = Length[vectors]/2;
x = Partition[vectors, 2];
slots = Slot /@ Range[len];
t = Graphics[
  Evaluate[Arrow[slots]] &[x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]], x[[5]]], 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: I think what you want is `Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[x, 2, 1], Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`?  There's no need for `Slot` kluge.

Comment: Well, that certainly simplifies things 

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    vectors = {0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, -1, 3, 4, 0};
    x = Partition[vectors, 2];
    Graphics[Map[Arrow, 
  Partition[Drop[Drop[Flatten[x /. {a_, b_} -> {{a, b}, {a, b}}, 1], 1], -1],2]]]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Graphics @ BlockMap[Arrow @ Partition[#, 2] &, vectors, 4, 2]
```

[image]